# Paste row between two values in Column A

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to perform a check - is selected cell within the range. Range is basically all rows between two words in column A.

```
CheckIfCellIsInBetween "OWN WORK FIRST", "OWN WORK LAST", 266
```

So if selected cell is between "OWN WORK FIRST" and "OWN WORK LAST". Code should work, otherwise error message should be displayed. I know that this is incorrect `If foundA Is Nothing Or foundB Is Nothing Then` but what it should be?

Current code:

```
Sub CheckIfCellIsInBetween(statementA, statementB, GanttDataRow)

    Dim foundA As Range, _
        foundB As Range

    With ActiveSheet.Columns(1)
        Set foundA = .Find(statementA)
        If Not foundA Is Nothing Then
            Set foundB = .Find(statementB, after:=foundA, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
        End If
    End With

    If foundA Is Nothing Or foundB Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You are trying to paste to wrong section, please go to Own Work section"
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttData").Rows(GanttDataRow).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).insert
    End If

End Sub
```

Current code does not perform check correctly, it pasts anywhere because current statement is always true in my case as it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to check instead:

```
Sub CheckIfCellIsInBetween(statementA, statementB, GanttDataRow)
If GanttDataRow > Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(statementA, Range("A:A"), 0) _
    And GanttDataRow < Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(statementB, Range("A:A"), 0) Then
    MsgBox "Correct selection"
Else
    MsgBox "Wrong selection"
End If
End Sub
```

This assumes that statementA and statementB are **guaranteed** to be in column A, otherwise it will through an error. If not, you can add a quick pre-check or an error catcher.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
Sub CheckIfCellIsInBetween(FirstStatemement, LastStatemement, GanttDataRow)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim StartRange, EndRange As Range
    Set StartRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find(what:=FirstStatemement, lookat:=xlPart)
    Set EndRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find(what:=LastStatemement, lookat:=xlPart)

    If ActiveCell.Row > StartRange.Row And ActiveCell.Row < EndRange.Row Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttData").Rows(GanttDataRow).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GanttChart").Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).insert
    Else
        MsgBox "You are trying to paste to wrong section, please go to Own Work section", vbExclamation, "Wrong section alert"
    End If
    
    ThisWorkbook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
   
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```